# typedef in header file not getting picked up by xcode

Tags: ios, cocoa, typedef, xcode4.6

I have a typedef in A.h file, and I import that A.h file in B.h that makes use of the same typedef.

For the longest time everything worked fine, but now it breaks complaining that it doesn't recognize the typedef and gives "Expect type" error in xcode, even tho xcode highlights the typedef in the second file, meaning that it knows they are defined else where.

if I manually redefine that typedef then the error goes away. but I get a warning that I am redefining a typedef and that it is a C11 feature.

I tried deleting the derived data, but the error stays. It looks like xcode is trying to look up the typedef before inserting the import files. Any clue?  I'm using xcode 4.6

```
//WebService.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface WebService : NSObject


typedef void(^loginUserWithUserNameandPaswordCompletion)(NSDictionary *, NSError*);

+(void)createUserWithName:(NSString*)name
                 andEmail:(NSString*)email
              andPassword:(NSString*)password
             onCompletion:(loginUserWithUserNameandPaswordCompletion) complete;
@end

//DataCenter.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "WebService.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

typedef void(^loginUserWithUserNameandPaswordCompletion)(NSDictionary *, NSError*);
@interface DataCenter : NSObject

+(void) logInUserWithEmail:(NSString*) email
               andPassword:(NSString*)password
              onCompletion:(loginUserWithUserNameandPaswordCompletion)complete;

@end
```

Comment: Can you put your declaration ?

Comment: "typedef in header file not getting picked up by xcode" - of course it isn't, Xcode is not the compiler.

Comment: @H2CO3 XCode does a lint of some sort. If it senses that you have a compile error it flags your error and blocks a build.I'll update with declarations.

Comment: @iphonic I updated the post with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used @class as mentioned by gberginc

Answer (score 2):

Try putting typedef before your `@interface` in `WebService.h`.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work... one more note, in AppDelegate.h I also import DataCenter.h, this is a triangular import

Comment: Try to avoid circular dependencies! Use forward declarations of classes instead of imports. To do this, remove those `#import`s of your own classes and put `@class <ClassName>` in front of `@interface`. Then put imports into your implementation files. You could also try putting typedef into a separate header file and import it in all other header files that require that typedef.

Comment: That's the correct solution, not repeating the `typedef` in both headers.